# c memset function puzzle

Tags: c, memset

I want to set an `int*` array to `null`. There are two ways to do this:

1.:

```
int* buf[8]; memset(buf, 0, sizeof(buf));
```

2.:

```
int* buf[8]; memset(&buf, 0, sizeof(buf));
```

They have the same result, but is there some difference?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They accomplish the same thing. `buf` evaluates to a pointer to the first element (`int*`) of the array, while `&buf` gets you a *pointer-to-array-of-8-`int*`s*. (The types differ in a somewhat obscure way.) Both of those pointers can be used to access the byte representation of the array via casting to `char*`, which is what `memset()` conceptually does. Internally, you're just passing the same address in both cases in practice.

As a pedantic note, it's not guaranteed that the internal representation of a `NULL` pointer is as all-zero bytes (though this is extremely likely in practice).

To directly declare a variable of type *pointer-to-array-of-8-`int*`s*, you could use the following by the way:

```
int* buf[8];
int* (*bufp)[8] = &buf; /* Initialize a pointer-to-array-of-8-int* */
```

`bufp` is different from a pointer to the first element of the array in that you can do e.g. `sizeof *bufp` to get the size of the array. (That information would not be available to the compiler with just a pointer to the first element. The above makes it inherent in the type.)

As seen above, pointers and arrays aren't the same thing (they have different types, and there are dedicated types for arrays). The reason people often confuse pointers and arrays is that arrays usually *evaluate to* a pointer to their first element. `sizeof` is one case where that does not happen. If the array degraded to a pointer with `sizeof`, then you'd get the size of that pointer instead of the size of the array, which wouldn't be useful.